# NEO4J - Using subquery in CASE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it right to use subquery inside CASE ?

```
MATCH (p:Person)
SET p.total =
CASE
WHEN HAS (p.total)
THEN p.total
ELSE 
MATCH (p)-[:CHILD]->(c)
RETURN sum(c.age)
END 
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

I get the following error when I try to do this.

> Invalid input ']': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map or a relationship pattern 
>   "           MATCH (p)-[:CHILD]->(c)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but there will be better ways in the future:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
SET p.total =
CASE WHEN HAS (p.total)
THEN p.total
ELSE reduce(sum = 0, path in (p)-[:CHILD]->() | sum + (nodes(path)[1]).age)
END 
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

or actually:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
SET p.total = 
COALSECE(p.total,
  reduce(sum = 0, path in (p)-[:CHILD]->() | sum + (nodes(path)[1]).age)
)
RETURN DISTINCT p
```